# matlab: generating function output variable with GUI input

Tags: matlab, user-interface, scope, output, nested-function

One of the functions of a software package I maintain is to parse a user's shorthand name for a product into its full name.  The software attempts 2 ways to do this automatically before kicking back to user input.  If the automatic attempts fail, the user is requested to match with a table.

The GUI portion is quite large, so it is maintained in its own subfunction.  The subfunction will only return the `idx` or index variable.  I am having difficulty with matlab being "patient" enough to wait for the GUI to specify idx.

Here is the important bits of the code with comments:

```
function [ idx ] = mnmhelper( modeldb )
%mnmhelper makes a UI table for the user to manually select the correct
%model

%% uitable generation

f = figure('UserData',1); %userdata will be the selection;
t = uitable('Parent',f,...
    'Data',modeldb.Model,...
    'CellSelectionCallback',@select_callback);
b = uicontrol('Parent', f,...
    'Style','pushbutton',...
    'String','Commit Model Name',...
    'Callback',@button_callback);

%% callbacks - note that these are nested in the parent fnc

    function select_callback(hObject , eventdata)
        %hObject - handle to uitable
        %eventdata - currently selected table indexes

        f.UserData = eventdata.Indices; % pass selection as userdata array: [row,col]
    end

    function button_callback(hObject,eventdata,selection)
        idx = f.UserData(1);
        close(f);
        figclosed = 1; %see additional notes below code on this line
    end
end
```

The issue is that matlab will error that idx was not defined, because it has not waited for the figure to be used.

I attempted to add the section:

```
%% strongarm matlab into waiting for user to do this

figclosed = 0;
while figclosed < 1 %don't evaluate to command line until figure is finished
    % ... do nothing 
    % once this evaluates to ==1 and kicks out of this, idx is defined
end
```

after all of the callbacks, but matlab will be waiting in the while loop and the figure does not generate.  How do I make matlab wait?

Do I need a `CreateFcn` for f that makes matlab wait or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `uiwait` function exists for just this purpose.  Simply call `uiwait(f)` to have matlab wait for the GUI figure to terminate.

See doc: [uiwait](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiwait.html).